# Configure Logstash to wait before parsing a file

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder, logstash-file, filebeat

I wonder if you can configure logstash in the following way:

Background Info:

- Every day I get a xml file pushed to my server, which should be parsed.
- To indicate a complete file transfer afterwards I get an empty .ctl (custom file) transfered to the same folder.
- The files both have the following name schema 'feedback_{year}{yearday}_UTC{hoursminutesseconds}_51.{extention}' (e.g. feedback_16002_UTC235953_51.xml). So they have the same file name but one is with .xml and the other is a .ctl file.

Question:

Is there a way to configure logstash to wait parsing the xml file until the according .ctl file is present?

EDIT:
Is there maybe a way to archiev that with filebeat?

EDIT2:
It would also be enough to be able to configure logstash in a way that it will wait x minutes before starting to process a new file, if that is easier.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Hi @d.a.d.a how did you manage to solve the issue? I have a similar use case in which I have to wait for a file being fully written in a specific directory before ingesting it

Comment: Oh wow it's been ages since this. I am sorry but I actually don't recall how we solved this. Probably like suggested by @alfredocambera suggested. Maybe also something like this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/wait-for-file-input-plugin-90-seconds/217627

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't want to start the parser before the file transfer hasn't been completed. So, why don't push the data to a file (file-complete.xml) when you find your flag file (empty.ctl)?

Here is the possible logic for a script and runs using crontab:

- if **empty.ctl** exists:

  - Clear **file-complete.xml**
  - Add the content of **file.xml** to **file-complete.xml**.
  - Remove **empty.ctl**

This way, you'd need to parse the data from file-complete.xml. I think is simpler to debug and configure.

Hope it helps,